# AndroidPlot: Positioning and Aligning domain value labels

Tags: android, graph, androidplot, android-graphview

I'm having trouble positioning and aligning the domain values in AndroidPlot. I've attached a screenshot of what I have so far.

**Problem 1 (Positioning):** Since I'm formatting Unix timestamp as MMM-yy and setting the domain label orientation to -90 degrees, the labels tends to overlap the graph area (as shown below). Is there a way to move the domain labels? I prefer **not** to use `setDomainLabelVerticalOffset()` as the `XYGraphWidget` doesn't re-size itself to accommodate the changes from offsetting.

**Problem 2 (Aligning):** The domain labels seem to be aligned from bottom. This is very clear if you look at "Jul-07" and "May-09" labels in the screenshot below. Is is possible to align the labels from top?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi, do you mind me asking how you got your domain labels vertical?

Comment: @NatalieCarr, I know it's a bit late, but here is how I did it. In XML I used `androidPlot.graphWidget.domainLabelOrientation="-90"` or alternatively at runtime using `plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(float)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is set the justification of the labels being drawn.  If memory serves, the default is center justified and what you probably want is right justified:

```
plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
```

Nick